# "Save as" and "Save and add another" in Admin

Tags: django

Is there a way to have both "save as" and "save and add another" in django admin site?

Comment: how would you do save as? every form either saves a new object and goes back to the list (save), saves a new object and goes back to the blank new object form (save and add another), or saves and remains on the edit page of that object (save and continue editing).

Comment: If you put save_as = True in your admin.py you get the save as button. But what this does is replace the save and add another button by a save as. But I want to be able to have the two choices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the URLs the buttons reference are in any way magic so you could probably add another button with the missing functionality by simply override the admin template per http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by overriding the default behaviour in `admin_modify.py` ( [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101281/in-django-admin-how-can-i-hide-save-and-continue-and-save-and-add-another-butto) this post helped me but didn't actually work for me)

This is a modification of the original source code from django 1.6. Place it in `/app/templatetags/admin_modify.py` (dont forget to import it in `/app/templatetags/__init__.py`)

```
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags import admin_modify

@admin_modify.register.inclusion_tag('admin/submit_line.html', takes_context=True)
def submit_row(context):
    opts = context['opts']
    change = context['change']
    is_popup = context['is_popup']
    save_as = context['save_as']
    ctx = {
        'opts': opts,
        'show_delete_link': (not is_popup and context['has_delete_permission']
                              and change and context.get('show_delete', True)),
        'show_save_as_new': not is_popup and change and save_as,
        'show_save_and_add_another': context['has_add_permission'] and
                            not is_popup,
        'show_save_and_continue': not is_popup and context['has_change_permission'],
        'is_popup': is_popup,
        'show_save': True,
        'preserved_filters': context.get('preserved_filters'),
    }
    if context.get('original') is not None:
        ctx['original'] = context['original']
    return ctx

admin_modify.submit_row = submit_row
```

The source code had:

```
'show_save_and_add_another': context['has_add_permission'] and
              not is_popup and (not save_as or context['add']),
```

Comment: I have to change file .../django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/submit_line.html too (to see the button) and type "from admin_modify import *" in /<app>/templatetags/__init__.py and it should work or I missed something?