# In Django admin, how can I hide Save and Continue and Save and Add Another buttons on a model admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-admin

I have a workflow for a model in the Django admin that is very similar to the users' workflow. First, I have a form with basic fields and then, a second form with the rest of the data.

It's the same workflow as auth.user

I need to remove "save and continue" and "save and add another" buttons to prevent the user breakoing the workflow.

I have tried to add it as extra_context:

```
extra_context = {
  'show_save_and_add_another': False,
  'show_save_and_continue': False
}
```

and pass it through ModelAdmin.add_view or ModelAdmin.change_view but it doesn't work.

This is only for one model, so I don't want to remove from submit_line.html

Any clue or alternative way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Beside its (a bit awkward) hacking style, you could aslo override the template tag directly.
Normally overriding template is more recommended.

```
# put this in some app such as customize/templatetags/admin_modify.py and place the app
# before the 'django.contrib.admin' in the INSTALLED_APPS in settings

from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_modify import *
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_modify import submit_row as original_submit_row
# or 
# original_submit_row = submit_row

@register.inclusion_tag('admin/submit_line.html', takes_context=True)
def submit_row(context):
    ctx = original_submit_row(context)
    ctx.update({
        'show_save_and_add_another': context.get('show_save_and_add_another', ctx['show_save_and_add_another']),
        'show_save_and_continue': context.get('show_save_and_continue', ctx['show_save_and_continue'])
        })                                                                  
    return ctx
```

Comment: I think this is actually the best approach. First, I tried to do what you explain in `# put this in some app such as customize/templatetags/admin_modify.py ...` but it didn't work. Then, I put this piece of code at the beginning of the admin.py file and it works perfect.

Comment: @ManuelAlvarez fine. Perhaps your `customize/templatetags/` lacked `__init__.py` and was thus not a package and got ignored. I'm not quite sure whether your `admin.py` solution works in all circumstances, we'll see :)

Comment: what's the purpose of that `import *` ?
I tried to delete it, and import all those functions one by one, but my custom submit_row method is not called anymore. Any ideeas why ?

Comment: @NiCU It's a quick typing to import all requisites. Importing one by one is more appropriate. Perhaps your tag does not override the original one, because your custom app places after the original app in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yeah, i had some issues there now it's fixed (umm... i guess i should delete my comments since are not really useful)

Comment: Update: using Django 1.8, I had to add 'show_save' and/or 'show_save_as_new' to both the submit_row tag and the change_view method of the Admin class.

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but does the above template tag solution depend on defining the 'extra_context'  values in a ModelAdmin's add or change view?

Comment: It works, but it changes all `change_form`. Someone might want to hide the buttons on the specific model.

Answer (score 13):

This isn't possible with an 'out of the box' option as far as I can tell, but this is how I'd go about doing what you want to do.

The bit of code we care about is [this templatetag](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_modify.py#L23) - this seems to override `show_save_and_add_another` and `show_save_and_continue` regardless of what you have set it to. It also creates a whole new context and copies only certain values across (not clear what the justification for this is), so you'll have to modify it to get what you need.

So:

1. Create a templatetag that replicates the functionality of the default tag, either by reusing the existing one (see [okm's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13106661/23746)) or by duplicating it entirely. The only change here is that it should either keep your `show_save_and_add_another` from the original context without overwriting it, or pass through your own `really_hide_save_and_add_another_damnit` context variable.
2. Replace change_form.html to include and use your own templatetag, replacing `submit_row` with it.
3. Update change_form.html if you've gone for the option of using an extra context variable, wrapping the buttons with another conditional statement.

Then, regardless of what option you went for, update your ModelAdmin with something like (based on [this from the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.history_view)):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['show_save_and_add_another'] = False
        # or
        extra_context['really_hide_save_and_add_another_damnit'] = True
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
            form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```

**Updated:** Original response didn't take in to account the submit_row not passing along any the whole original context.

Comment: It works well and I can test my 'really_hide_save_and_add_another_damnit' new var on change_form.html but it seems that I can't do it in submit_line.html since its value is '' in all cases. I've tried to test, check, print,... the value without success. Do I need to load any aditional library at the beginning of the template?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise the submit_row templatetag doesn't copy the whole context across - only certain items. You'll need to override this templatetag, either entirely, or using okm's option.

Answer (score 5):

A very different approach can be to add the following in 
/static/admin/css/base.css

```
input[name="_addanother"],input[name="_continue"],input[name="_saveasnew"]{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove **"Save and continue editing" button** and **"Save and add another" button**, set **"False"** to **"extra_context['show_save_and_continue']"** in **"changeform_view()"** and return **"False"** in **"has_add_permission()"** respectively as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}

        extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False # Here

        return super().changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None): # Here
        return False
```