# Override existing Django Template Tags

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, templatetags

Is it possible to override an existing Django Template Tag? or is it necessary to customize the template file and create a new Template Tag?

Comment: Yes, its possible. For example http://stackoverflow.com/a/13106661/165603

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

As django is basically a python library (as with everything in python) you can over-write anything you'd like.

It's not clear exactly what you'd like to do but it really is pretty easy to roll-your-own templatetag, the docs are pretty clear:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

This is crazy basic but this is the kind of template I use to start building a custom template tag from:

myapp/templatetags/my_custom_tags.py
(must have `__init__.py` in this directory)

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

class CustomTag(template.Node):
    def render(self, context):
        context['my_custom_tag_context'] = "this is my custom tag, yeah"
        return ''

@register.tag(name='get_custom_tag')
def get_custom_tag(parser, token):
    return CustomTag()
```

Usage in your template goes like this:

```
{% load my_custom_tags %}
{% get_custom_tag %}
{{my_custom_tag_context}}
```

You probably want to parse the `token`, and you probably want some kind of `__init__` in the class, but it does go to show how basic it is.

---

You can browse through the existing 'default' templatetags, replicate and modify them to your heart's content.

There really is some great stuff there:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py

Comment: Well, this example shows how to create a new Tag, but how is it possible to override this existing tag in a separate py-file? I dont wanna touch the template file when it isnt necessary.

Answer (score 22):

I was looking for the same answer, so figured I'd share my solution here. I wanted to override the default url template tag in django without having to use a custom template tag and load it in every template file.

The goal was to replace %20 (spaces) with + (pluses). Here's what I came up with...

In  `__init__.py`

```
from django.template.defaulttags import URLNode

old_render = URLNode.render
def new_render(cls, context):
  """ Override existing url method to use pluses instead of spaces
  """
  return old_render(cls, context).replace("%20", "+")
URLNode.render = new_render
```

This page was useful https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py

Comment: for edification, this is very similar to rails alias_method_chain functionality minus the "without" semantics.

Comment: @ncavig hello, in which "init.py" did you do this?

Answer (score 10):

I assume by "an Existing Django Template Tag" you mean a tag in a different app.

Create a `templatetags/tagfile.py` that registers a tag with the same name. Make sure that `tagfile` is the same name that the template loads with `{% load tagfile %}` for getting the original tag.

Also, make sure your app is listed after the original app in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: A similar idea: you can load in the `register` object from the other library (the other library should have something like `register = template.Library()` and then it registers tags by doing `@register.tag` etc. You can import `register` instead of instantiating your own, and do `@register.tag(tag_name='existing_tag')`

Comment: This is probably the best solution!

Comment: ...unfortunately it gives me the warning `(templates.E003) 'admin_list' is used for multiple template tag modules: 'myapp.templatetags.admin_list', 'someapp.templatetags.admin_list'`.

Answer (score 5):

I am pretty sure you are asking for complete override of a django `templatetag`.

The short answer is - `Yes`, you can override an existing `templatetag`.

Here is how to achieve it:

- You have to have your template directory included in the `settings`:

```
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_app/templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                    'django.template.context_processors.static',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

- You have to include the app you want to override a `templatetag` for, in the 
  `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'your_app_name',
        ...
    ]
```

#### The important bit is to have your app after django's apps !

This is due to the way django works. We will get use right of that.

- Now, create a folder inside your app, named `templatetags`. It is important to have `__init__.py` file inside the `templatetags`, so django could understand it is a python package!:

`your_app_name/templatetags/__init__.py`.

- Create the `templatetag` you want to override. In that example, i'll use the `admin_list.py` tag.

In that case, it should be placed like this:

`your_app_name/templatetags/admin_list.py`

- Now copy the entire content of the `admin_list.py`  (VERY IMPORTANT!)
  from `django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_list.py` and modify whatever you want.

It is important to have the whole content of the django's admin `admin_list.py` and not only a piece of code, else it would not work!

---

How it works:
Django is looking in your application for `templatetags` folder and uses the template tags inside of it. It places yours template tags after the `admin's` ones and in short - it overrides them since they are placed after `django.admin` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Do not forget to:

- `./manage.py collectstatic`
- set `DEBUG = False`

in production.

I have tested it already for `result_list(cl)` function override, and it is working.

---

This solution works event without custom html template files.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No way to "extend" the existing templatetag file, similar to how we do with Django templates?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to depend on the order of your app inside the settings.py `INSTALLED_APPS`, then you can try the following:

Create the templatetag function/class as usual. Say you want to override a templatetag named `otherapp_tags.current_time` from an app named `other_app`. First, create your own version of that function/class:

```
def my_current_time(format_string):
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format_string)
```

then, instead of registering this function/class inside YOUR apps namespace, patch the existing function from the other app:

```
from other_app.templatetags import otherapp_tags

otherapp_tags.register.tags['current_time'] = my_current_time
```

Typically you should do this inside your `AppConfig`'s `ready()` method.

Answer (score 1):

The actually most voted solution has one major drawback for me - you need to redefine all tags. For some projects, that can be a big drawback. How to solve that? As mentioned by [m_floer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884640/m-floer), it's best to import the register instance from the outside module. So how it should look? Code was taken from Django Jazzmin:

**What I want to do? Overwrite the only one template tag: `get_side_menu` tag.**
The tag is located in `jazzmin.templatetags.jazzmin`, so in our app we will create module  `templatetags` with file `jazzmin.py`. And the contents will be:

```
...
from jazzmin.templatetags.jazzmin import register


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True, name="get_side_menu")
def get_side_menu(context: Context, using: str = "available_apps") -> List[Dict]:
    ...  # your template tag code
```

This will override just and only selected Django template tag in the easiest way possible. Be aware, that it's for all apps in the given project!

Answer (score 0):

You can override Django Template Tags. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122141/how-to-create-a-custom-template-tags-in-django/76550947#76550947) explaining how to create Django Template Tags.

First, create `templatetags` folder with `__init__.py`(Empty file) and `custom_tags.py` in `core` folder where `settings.py` is as shown below, then don't forget to restart server to apply `custom_tags.py` to Django project. *Other names are fine for `custom_tags.py` and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048232/what-does-load-do-in-django-templates/76250176#76250176) explaining [templatetags folder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout) and [load tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#load):

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-templatetags # Here
 |     |-__init__.py
 |     └-custom_tags.py
 |-templates
 |  └-index.html
 |-app1
 └-app2
```

And, don't forget to set `core` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` to apply `custom_tags.py` to Django project as shown below. *Setting `core` to `INSTALLED_APPS` also can collect the static files in `core` folder to the root Django Project folder with `python manage.py collectstatic`. I recommend to set `core` to `INSTALLED_APPS` before you start building your Django Project:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'core', # Here
    'app1',
    'app2',
]
```

Next, override `comment` tag in `custom_tags.py` as shown below. *You can see the original [comment tag](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/template/defaulttags.py#L563) in `/django/template/defaulttags.py`:

```py
# "custom_tags.py"

from django.template import Library, Node

register = Library()

@register.tag
def comment(parser, token):
    parser.skip_past('endcomment')
    return CommentNode()

class CommentNode(Node):
    def render(self, context):
        return 'This is not a comment.' # This part is changed.
```

Then, use the overridden comment tag as shown below:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% load custom_tags %}

{% comment %}{% endcomment %}
```

Then, this below is displayed:

```
This is not a comment.
```