# Tenancy and sub-tenancy in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, multi-tenant

I'm having a SaaS application which needs a main user (like the owner of the business who would use the SaaS) to be the admin of that particular tenancy. Now the main user needs of have multiple sub users (like a user looking for sales, other for purchase, etc).

Now my question is single level tenancy is possible in Django. How can I do the second one?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django multi tenancy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938338/django-multi-tenancy)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at foreign key based fields in particular the many to many field. You can then use manytomany through a role object which captures information about roles i.e.

See the django docs for excellent examples