# Capture subdomains with wildcard to a view (Django)

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm trying to figure out how to capture a subdomain with the URL Dispatcher and making it do something with a view.

For instance, this is a typical URL:

```
url(r'^contact/', include('django_website.contact.urls')),
```

But what if I had a site with the Django **sites** module and wanted to make different thing with that url or ALL subdomain urls?

url() for what I know do not allow me to add regular expressions to subdomains?

To demonstrate (not accurate, but with a wildcard):

```
url(r'*.mysite.com', 'views.subdomain', name='subdomain'),
```

**views.py:**

```
def subdomain(request):
   # something here
```

I haven't come across an example like this online. How could I do this?

Comment: ^If my answer isn't usable, the comment by burhan khalid on that provides a list of every possible other package that can achieve it

Comment: Sayse: That explain most of it. But how do I run this without nginx (just my Django dev server)?

Comment: See the link in [Burhan Khalid's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938338/django-multi-tenancy#comment48000989_29938338)