# Django Multiple users per customer for a SaaS application

Tags: python, django, django-models, multi-tenant, django-authentication

I'm working with a SaaS application idea. I need to create a Django User system, where a customer register for the SaaS app. Then the customer can have multiple sub-users as needed.

How can I design the Django Authentication system and the models to have something like this?

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django multi tenancy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938338/django-multi-tenancy)

Answer (score 2):

Multi tenancy is one option, otherwise you can use [django-organizations](https://django-organizations.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) so a user could be a member of multiple organizations and have the option to select the active one (for example a consultant)