# How to create multi-tenant system using django?

Tags: mysql, django, mongodb, multi-tenant

Are there common patterns people use for creating multi-tenanted applications using Django. The built in "sites" framework seems like an option. Are there other approaches people have had success with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django multi tenancy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938338/django-multi-tenancy)

Answer (score 1):

Found the way, you can use already created application, its  pribuilt app.

[django tenant schemas](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas)