# Wildcard Subdomains with Django + Gunicorn + Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I'm trying to enable subdomains for users on my `domain.com` which runs on Django, Gunicorn and Nginx as reverse proxy. domain.com has wildcard SSL and I have already added subdomain CName in DNS settings. I have also written a middleware to render `username.domain.com` programatically in Django. This is how my nginx conf file looks like -

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name *.domain.com;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/path/to/djangoapp/appname.sock;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }
} 
server {
     listen 443;
     ssl on;
     server_name *.domain.com;

     ssl_certificate /certificate/path/cert.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /certificate/key/cert.key;
     location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to pass all subdomain requests to my django app so that I can handle it programatically. How do I enable this in Nginx?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938338/django-multi-tenancy?lq=1 This solution doesn't work. Nginx is not able to forward the request to gunicorn.sock.

Comment: That is my own solution that I do use, and yes it does work correctly (for me at least). Although, admittedly my actual implementation does have slight changes to it (involving a `proxy_pass` to an `upstream` for example)

Comment: In fact, I tried setting up an upstream block , but it didn't help. It's showing default nginx html page for all subdomains.It's not hitting Django middleware at all, except the main domain.com and www.domain.com.

Comment: I was just sticking up for my own solution :P I can assure you it does work for me.. Did you restart nginx after changing the conf? I'm afraid I can't be any more help.. otherwise check the list of other django packages in that list, not sure if any of those offer solutions

Comment: Does it require any additional setting in DNS ? I have an `A` record with * as name and it's pointing to the main IP. Along with it, I have 2 more `A` records , one for www and other one is domain name.

Comment: Sorry its been a while since I've had to do it so I'm a bit rusty.. I can't remember having to do anything extra