# Point subdomains to subdirectories with nginx (nginx + https + gunicorn + django)

Tags: django, nginx, https, gunicorn, subdomain

I have https://testsite.com working on django + gunicorn + nginx + https.

My nginx conf (everything fine):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name testsite.com;
    access_log off;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name *.testsite.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;

    # lots of sll staff

    location / {
        # point to gunicorn
        proxy_pass http://176.112.198.254:8000/;
    }
}
```

I need to implement cities on subdomains pointing to subdirectories (exept main_city).

So i need urls like this:

https://testsite.com/some_url/ should point to https://testsite.com/main_city/some_url/
https://city1.testsite.com/some_url/ should point to https://testsite.com/city1/some_url/
https://city2.testsite.com/some_url/ should point to https://testsite.com/city2/some_url/

How can i do that?

Big thx for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django multi tenancy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938338/django-multi-tenancy)

Comment: @Sayse, Nothing about ssl and https

Comment: I was more referring to the link contained in that answer that hosts every possible package that has been made to help support this

Answer (score 1):

You have to define upstrem directive. Currently your nginx can not proxy to your web application.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

```
upstream backend {
    server backend1.example.com       weight=5;
    server backend2.example.com:8080;
    server unix:/tmp/backend3;

    server backup1.example.com:8080   backup;
    server backup2.example.com:8080   backup;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```