# django load URLS based on subdomain

Tags: django, subdomain, django-urls

I am facing a problem here dealing with subdomains.

Taking wix.com as an example, how do I do this?

```
www.mysite.com/page1 => load r'^page1/$'from URLS_main.py

user1.mysite.com/page1 => load r'^page1/$' from URLS_users.py
```

currently I am using a middleware to determine the subdomain part, but I can't figure out the back part of it without doing lots of redirecting in the views or middleware.

Here is what my middleware does if it is relevant:

```
class subdomainMiddleware:

def process_request(self,request):
    domain_parts = request.get_host().split('.')
    subdomain = "www"
    if(len(domain_parts) > 2):
        subdomain = domain_parts[0].lower()

    request.subdomain = subdomain
```

Comment: [django-hosts](https://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides that functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django multi tenancy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938338/django-multi-tenancy)