# URL parameter before the domain name in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to configure my urls something like these:

```
username1.mysite.com
username2.mysite.com
```

You know, the parameter is actually the username, and its placed before the domain name. Other sites do this I have seen, for example, Wordpress Blogs and so on. Can I do this using Django URLs? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django multi tenancy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938338/django-multi-tenancy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled up django-subdomains which does exactly what I want. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a way to do this using Django's URLs because this is a subdomain NOT a URL parameter. What I would suggest is reading the subdomain in your server config (e.g nginx site config) and writing it into a header to be read by some custome middleware in django

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished something like this with the "django-dynamicsites" plugin.

https://bitbucket.org/uysrc/django-dynamicsites

It's quite old and may need a few tweaks for modern Djangos but it does do what you need, I use it myself and it works well.

It involves modifying the django_sites table so doesn't play too nice with makemigrations.  You may have to use the SQL to update the SQL database on your server to get around that.