# Django OVERRIDE default templatetags

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to make {% url %} fail silently if no reverse match is found and just output a simple '#' or default homepage link.

How can I accomplish this without adding `{% load tags %}` to my 100s of HTMLs? Kind of like monkey-patching but something production-ready.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The only reason you would get a NoReverseMatch error would be because of a mistake in the template.

Comment: look at this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223633/override-existing-django-template-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223633/override-existing-django-template-tags)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work,
create a file named 'builtins.py' in any app which look like this

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaulttags import url
from django.urls.exceptions import NoReverseMatch

register = template.Library()


def decorator(func):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except NoReverseMatch:
            return '#'
    return wrap


@register.tag(name='url')
def custom_url(parser, tokens):
    url_node = url(parser, tokens)
    url_node.render = decorator(url_node.render)
    return url_node
```

and in your `settings.py` file

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'builtins': ['app_name.builtins'],  # <-- Here
        },
    },
]
```

app_name is where you created your `builtins.py`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments this is not something you generally want to do. However, one way would be to use a variable:

```
{% url "some:url" as the_url %}
{{ the_url|default:"#"}}
```

This can also be written on a single line:

```
<a href="{% url "some:url" as the_url %}{{ the_url|default:"#"}}">...</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this would make THOUSANDS of changes it is a huge project, so it's not really feasible.