# Add keys to Django i18n loaded Tags

Tags: django, django-templates, internationalization

I'm trying to add a key to my all languages in my project

After `{% load static i18n %}` I have this loop in my template to help me investigate:

```
  {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
  {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
  {% for language in languages %}
    {{ language }}
  {% endfor %}
```

and the output looks like this:

```
{'bidi': False, 'code': 'en-gb', 'name': 'British English', 'name_local': 'British English', 'name_translated': 'Inglês Britânico'}
{'bidi': False, 'code': 'pt-br', 'name': 'Brazilian Portuguese', 'name_local': 'Português Brasileiro', 'name_translated': 'Português Brasileiro'}
```

I would like to add to this dictionary another key like `'lang_simple': 'en'` or `'lang_simple': 'pt'`, but haven't figured where this dictionary is coming from so I can add my new key.

I tried looking for it using this answer, but didn't get very far: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20009830/7091922

If anybody has an idea, please let me know!

Happy new year!

Comment: If your `lang_simple` is `simple`, then a work around could be to slice the `code`.

Comment: Awesome!! Yeah, this worked `{{ language.code|slice:2 }}`