# Override template in django admin

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm using Django 1.11

1. I was able to extend/override one template called `change_form.html`

   I placed this file under `/templates/admin/my_app/my_model/`

   For this one I extended and changed one block, like in the [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template) in django docs
2. I was **not** able to override one template called `submit_line.html`

   I tried placing it under `/templates/admin/`, `/templates/admin/my_app/`, and `/templates/admin/my_app/my_model/`. None worked.

   I edited the file under `django/contrib` and it worked, but I don't want to change **that file**. It was just to see if the content was showing.

I just want to add one button to the template, so the user can download one XML file.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101281/in-django-admin-how-can-i-hide-save-and-continue-and-save-and-add-another-butto/13106661#13106661). I think it's what you need ;)

Comment: This considers that my needs are in the template and I can hide the elements. I need to add one button

Comment: You can follow the guidelines in this answer and override the `'admin/submit_line.html'` template. Inside that template is the row of buttons. But this template in rendered through this inclusion tag.

Comment: Right, but before I get to this point my app has to first pick up my `admin/submit_line.html` file. It nos finding apparently and there is no way to find out why.

Comment: This template will be found upon creating this inclusion tag. Set the appropriate path and it should work. On the other hand, if that doesn't work, there is another solution. Use `jQuery` to "edit" the `change_form.html` and add the button.

Comment: I was able to use the templatetag to show and hide the current buttons, but I could not add any information over there. How can I use jQuery to modify the file?! I can't load my file

Comment: I agree that is a different question to load the jQuery file, but my question remains unanswered. As I put in the title "Override template in django admin". Since the beginning I've been saying that I am not able to override the file and this exactly what is still happening. My file is not found even though its path is `/templates/admin/submit_file.html`. Besides, you didn't put as an answer either... Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some tests and research here is the solution.

First, underneath `/templates/admin/my_app/my_model/` copy-paste the `submit_line.html` from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/`.

Change `submit_line.html` and add any urls you like. Say:

```
<!-- submit_line.html -->

{% load i18n admin_urls %}
<div class="submit-row">
{% if show_save %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" class="default" name="_save" />{% endif %}
{% if show_delete_link %}
    {% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' original.pk|admin_urlquote as delete_url %}
    <p class="deletelink-box"><a href="{% add_preserved_filters delete_url %}" class="deletelink">{% trans "Delete" %}</a></p>
{% endif %}

<!-- NEW SUBMIT INPUTS -->
<input type="submit" value="TEST" name="_saveasnewss" />
<input type="submit" value="TEST 2" name="_saveasnews" />
<!-- END NEW SUBMIT INPUTS -->

{% if show_save_as_new %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save as new' %}" name="_saveasnew" />{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_add_another %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and add another' %}" name="_addanother" />{% endif %}
{% if show_save_and_continue %}<input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save and continue editing' %}" name="_continue" />{% endif %}
</div>
```

We're copy-pasting it because there aren't any `{% block %}` tags inside the `change_form.html` to override.

Further on, inside the `change_form.html`, add these:

```
<!-- change_form.html -->

{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% load my_app_tags %} /* Change "my_app" to your app name that will contain the 'submit_row' template tag */

OTHER OVERRIDES HERE

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% submit_row %}{% endblock %}
```

Finally, in your app's `templatetags`, add this template tag:

```
# my_app/templatetags/my_app_tags.py

from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_modify import submit_row
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django import template

# this would be the path to your "submit_line.html"
t = get_template('admin/my_app/my_model/submit_line.html')
register = template.Library()
register.inclusion_tag(t, takes_context=True)(submit_row)
```

That's it! Now you should see these extra `<input type="submit" />` only under `my_model` add/change page. If you want them globally just move `submit_line.html` from where it is to `templates/admin/`. Don't forget to update the paths inside `my_app/templatetags/my_app_tags.py` too.

Comment: Hey, I know this is not supposed to have thanks and stuff, but thank you for your patience and help on this issue writing all that code. It worked here. I only had to make a little adjustment (adding register) to make it work. :)